# angular return date to formControl MatDatePicker in DD-MM-YYYY format

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, formgroups

How can I bring the date correctly to the `formControl`?

When trying to set the date via `setValue`, it does not appear in the same format anymore.

I want the date to appear in the `DD-MM-YYYY` format, the same as I bring it in, but when doing the return via code, the component only accepts `MM-DD-YYYY`.

I have already tried to invert the DD with MM via code and return, but still nothing done.

**HTML**

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker4" placeholder="Data prevista pagamento" formControlName="dataPrevistaPagto">
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker4"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker #picker4></mat-datepicker>
```

I bring in the date like this:

**TS**

```
ModelEdit.dataPrevistaPagto = this.setDate(this.form.get('dataPrevistaPagto').value);

setDate(dataString: string){
  var today = new Date(dataString);
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  var dataa = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
  return dataa;
}
```

And I set the date like this:

```
this.form.get('dataPrevistaPagto').setValue( moment(new Date(this.setDateInverse(this.ModelEdit.dataPrevistaPagto))));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try implementing it using `Angular Date Pipe`
Have had an existing [Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-component-date-pipe) for your reference.

Just change the current format from Stackblitz `yyyy-MM-dd` to your desired format `dd-MM-yyyy` or other similar as per on [Angular Date Pipe Documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

```
@Component({
  ..., 
  providers: [ DatePipe ]    // Import DatePipe from "@angular/core"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {

  currentDate: any = new Date();

  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // You can use whatever format you like
    // see https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#pre-defined-format-options
    this.currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.currentDate, 'dd-MM-yyyy');

  }

}
```

Comment: but I can pipe my matdatepicker? If it was an input text I would be able to return normal, the problem is in that matDatePicker that I can not find a way

Comment: I got it. I was saving the date value as string. I altered it, and saved it the way it came from datePicker. And I used the pipe you recommended to display on my table. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Pedro, sorry for the late reply. Im glad it worked! Thank you very much :)